# If $\mathbb{C}[G]$ is Noetherian and $G$ has a representation on $V$, when must $V$ be finite-dimensional?

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, representation-theory

I know this is a bit vague, but please bare with me here.

Let's assume that $G$ is a finitely-generated torsion group. I want to show that $G$ is a finite group if I add some conditions. I suspect that $G$ must actually be finite *if* the group algebra $\mathbb{C}[G]$ is a Noetherian ring.

Here's my line of attack: say I have a representation $\rho: G \rightarrow GL(V)$ on some vector space $V$. (I have a specific $V$ in mind, with the property that if $\dim(V) < \infty$ then $G$ must be finite as long as $G$ is a finitely-generated torsion group.) I'd like to throw some other condition on $G$ in order to force $V$ to be finite-dimensional.

Is there such a condition? I mean maybe there's a way to correspond subspaces of $V$ with ideals of $\mathbb{C}[G]$ in an order-preserving, one-to-one manner. Then an increasing chain of subspaces would correspond to an increasing chain of ideals, so that's where I can use the Noetherian-ness.

Here's an idea: if I have a subspace $W$ of $V$, let $\operatorname{Fix}(W)$ be the set of $g\in G$ such that $\rho(g)w=w$ for every $w\in W$. Now $\operatorname{Fix}(W)$ is indeed a subgroup of $G$; however, "fixing" subspaces is an inclusion *reversing* operation. I want an operation which *preserves* inclusion.

Feel free to throw some additional assumptions on $V$ or $G$. I would really like $V$ to be finite-dimensional somehow. At the end of the day, I want to use this to show that $G$ must be finite, so we shouldn't assume that $G$ is solvable or something like that (because it's already been proven that $G$ is finite in that case).

EDIT: The space $V$ I have in mind consists of harmonic functions on the Cayley graph of $G$. There is the obvious representation of $G$ on $V$, and the rigidity of harmonic functions shows that if the kernel of this representation has finite index in $G$, then $\dim(V)=1$. But a theorem of Kleiner (2007) says that the index is infinite if $G$ is infinite. This is why I'm interested in this specific space.

Comment: You say *I have a very specific $V$ in mind*. I think it would be best if you explained what it is. Asking "Under what conditions is this representation I'm thinking of finite dimensional?" is not very good practice.

Comment: It actually doesn't matter what $V$ is, so I didn't want to clutter the OP with that detail. If you're curious, here's the idea.

Choose a finite generating set $S$ for $G$, and suppose for simplicity that $S$ is closed under taking inverses. The space $V$ consists of functions $f : G \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that

$f(x) = \frac{1}{|S|}\sum_{s\in S} f(xs)$

for every $x\in G$.

I want to know if there is some useful way of concluding that $V$ must be finite-dimensional by assuming some property of $G$. But I'm interested in knowing that in general, not just for this specific $V$.

Comment: The extra information improves the post a lot: thanks for taking the time.